# how to custmize iframe scroll bar with css or JS

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css

Is there any way that we customize iframe scroll bar with css or js please visit [link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/fr8Vf/3/)

Comment: Please share more information !! and what exactly you want ? Customize means what exactly

Comment: Please go to the http://jsfiddle.net/fr8Vf/7/ there you will see iframe scroll-bar which I want customize(Different color, style etc like its normally work with DIV)

Comment: Try to reference this link http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, the problem is not about the DIV as its work fine, I am looking this same style on iframe scroll bar

Comment: it will also work but dont apply for the iframe. use it for a div inside an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Refer one of these links:

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

it is fully customizable..

Comment: second link is broken